# Use multirow in S column

Tags: siunitx, multirow, s-column-type

I am using the `S` column from the `siunitx` package to align numbers, which works perfectly. However, now I would like some numbers to span several rows, using `multirow`, which gives me an error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lcS}    
\toprule
\textbf{Characteristic} & \textbf{Criterion} & \textbf{No. of components} \\
\midrule
Length [m] & $>0$ & 5343 \\
\multirow{3}{*}{Factor [-]} & $[0;1]$ & \multirow{3}{*}{12160} \\
& $[0;3]$ &  \\
& $[0;4.5]$ &  \\
\midrule
\textbf{Total} &  & 32124 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{caption}
\label{label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

In the leftmost column, the `multirow` works fine; however, in the rightmost column (`S` column), something is not working.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lcS}
    \toprule
\textbf{Characteristic} & \textbf{Criterion} & {\textbf{No. of components}} \\ % <---
    \midrule
Length [m]              & $>0$               & 5343     \\
\multirow{3}{*}{Factor [-]}
                        & $[0;1]$            & {\multirow{3}{*}{12160}}     \\ % <---
                        & $[0;3]$            &          \\
                        & $[0;4.5]$          &          \\
    \midrule
\textbf{Total}          &                   & 32124     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{caption}
\label{label}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

that above mwe works you need to enclose all non number contents in `S` columns in curly braces. however in your case is worth to consider to omit `multirow` and places its content to the middle row from the spanned:

```
\begin{tabular}{lcS[table-format=5.0]}
    \toprule
\textbf{Characteristic} & \textbf{Criterion} & {\textbf{No. of components}} \\ % <---
    \midrule
Length [m]              & $>0$               & 5343     \\
                        & $[0;1]$            &          \\ 
Factor [-]              & $[0;3]$            & 12160    \\
                        & $[0;4.5]$          &          \\
    \midrule
\textbf{Total}          &                    & 32124    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

which gives:

[image]