# Why is \tablenum{} needed for correct table alignment using siunitx and multirow?

Tags: tables, align, siunitx, multirow

I am trying to typeset a very big and complicated table and was struggling to correctly align the last column (the 10 in the MWE should not be centered but under the last two 0s of the 7000000 above it).

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368679/siunitx-incompatible-with-multirow) helped to add the {} around `\multirow` to correctly typeset the numbers but they are still not aligned properly and get centered instead. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/466811/use-multirow-in-s-column) is just resolving the alignment problem by getting rid of the `\multirow`, which I cannot do due to the rest of the table (not in the MWE).

Finally, I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356827/problem-with-siunitx-and-multirow/356851#356851) which made it work by replacing the `\num` in the MWE by `\tablenum`. But why is that the case? Why can siunitx not pick it up by itself, even when I give it the additional help of the curly brackets?

I spent so long trying to make this complicated table, so if anyone can answer my last open question, I would be super grateful!

A very reduced MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
    \caption{Caption}
\begin{center}
    \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{
l
S[table-format=7.0,group-separator={,}]
S[table-format=7.0,group-separator={,}]}

\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{C9C9C9} 
\textbf{Subcategories} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Long title 1\\      (in USD)\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Long title 2\\      (in USD)\end{tabular}}}  \\ \hline
1.1.1 Long row name &  500000 & \\ \cline{1-2}
1.1.2 Row name & 0 & \\ \cline{1-2}
1.1.3 Row name &  1000000 &  \\ \cline{1-2}
1.1.4 Other -   Name & 0 & {\multirow{-4}{*}{\num{7000000}}}\\ \cline{1-3}
1.2.1 Even longer row name  & 100000 &  \\ \cline{1-2}
1.2.2 Other -   name &  0 & {\multirow{-2}{*}{\num{10}}} \\
\hline

\end{tabular}

}
\end{center}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\multirow` suppresses the effects of an `S` column. Also: Never use `\resizebox` on a `tabular`. That's wrong. Also, inside of a float you don't want to use `\begin{center}` but `\centering` (`\begin{center}` leads to incorrect spacing).

Comment: Also, the "additional help" of curly braces is just telling `siunitx` to not use this with the normal alignment of `S`-type columns, anything in curly braces gets typeset centred (that's documented behaviour, and usually used for the head row).

Comment: I actually knew about the centering one, just forgot. Will need to look up why resizebox is wrong though.

Comment: @Skillmon If the curly brackets make the alignment to be ignored, why does it then work with \tablenum plus the braces and it still aligns it properly even though I am still using S?

Comment: `\resizebox` gives inconsistent font sizes (which is wrong). Better use `\small` or similar on the `tabular` to make it fit, suppress the outer most horizontal spacing using `@{}` at the begin and end of the `tabular` preamble, and change the `\tabcolsep` to be smaller. `\tablenum` is created in such a way that it aligns with an `S` type column even if not part of an `S` type column (see `siunitx`'s documentation).

Comment: From the documentation: "Within more complex tables, aligned numbers may be desirable within the argument of `\multicolumn` or `\multirow`. The `\tablenum` function is available to achieve alignment in these situations: this is, in effect, a macro version of the `S` column (Table 9)."